# Delayed publication of the subject with related items

Tags: publishing

Whether Sitecore allows you to set up delayed item publication with related items?

There is an item with a `layout` (page) that has a `placeholder` with components and I would like to publish all dependent `DataSource` for components when publishing a delayed page.
If so, how to do it?

**Sitecore version -> 8.2**

I don't have any workflows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ootb solution for doing this. You can delay publication of items by setting publish restrictions: https://doc.sitecore.com/users/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/set-up-publishing-restrictions-for-an-item.html

If you want to have those items published automatically you also need to enable auto-publish (maybe check this question as well: [Auto publishing for specific items](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/2053/237)).

Problem with the ootb publish restrictions for you is that it would need to be set on all related items. You might consider not doing that and let the related items be published sooner, but only do that if they are not accessible directly (e.g. don't do that for a media asset).

If the ootb functionality won't fit the needs, you'll need to go custom.

Comment: I thought so, probably the same restrictions are in versioning - I create item site version, and separately I need to create a DataSource version for components?

Comment: Indeed, it's the same "issue".